# addClass is not adding "hidden", but it can add anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an odd problem

in one event, i removed hidden from some classes:

```
      $(e.target).closest(".container-info").find(".divider, .content-holder, .post-date-holder").removeClass("hidden")
```

then in another event, i just want to add hidden again:

```
$(e.target).closest(".container-info").find(".divider, .content-holder, .post-date-holder").addClass("hidden")
```

The problem is, when I check the sources, addClass is not adding hidden at all, but if i write anything else instead of hidden, for example: ffff, it will be add in the class. 
Could anyone help me on this problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary **to reproduce it** in the question itself.

Comment: Could you provide your specific code for more details?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add !important to class ".hidden" in css file or style tag like this sample code:

```
.hidden{display:none !important}
```

Comment: you mean the problem comes from css file? because i am not responsible for that. But removeClass("hidden") is working well!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your "remove" handler fires after the "add" one. Could you please clarify when the events get triggered? Could you rename "hidden" in the remove handler for testing and check if "hidden" then gets applied by the "add" handler?

Comment: thank you so much for your response. When user clicks on a bucks, few information, like a list appear. They have "hidden" in their classes by default. First i remove "hidden" from classes to show the list. Beside the list, there is a button to close that information, i want to add "hidden" again by using this button. But it can add everything in the class, except "hidden".